# Geofencing events not working on simulator (Xamarin.ios)

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, geolocation, ios-simulator, geofencing

I have a problem with firing geofence events on Xamarin.ios . I remember I used to have it working using the same methods in the past. Right now it doesn't work somehow.
I'm using the following code to start monitoring:

> CLLocationManager locMan = new CLLocationManager();
>   locMan.RequestWhenInUseAuthorization();
>   locMan.RequestAlwaysAuthorization();
>   locMan.RegionEntered += (sender,
>   e) => {   Console.WriteLine("You've entered the region"); };
>
> locMan.RegionLeft += (sender, e) => {     Console.WriteLine("You've left
>   the region"); };
>
> CLCircularRegion aRegion2 = new CLCircularRegion(new
>   CLLocationCoordinate2D(30.432, 97.7360), 100, "apple test");
>   locMan.StartMonitoring(aRegion2);

And that's one demo project that I'm trying to test the geofence events on but not working :
https://github.com/aproram/Xamarin_ios_geofence_issue_demo

I'm testing the location change from the simulator menu (Debug->locaiton->custom location). Sometimes I get this message in the console output while changing the location:

> [Client] #Spi, Interrupted

Development environment:
Visual Studio v8.1
Xamarin.iOS Version: 12.10.0.153
xCode 10.1
Simulator iphone 6s (ios 12.1)

One thing to mention, I tried testing geofencing with an xCode SWIFT project and the events were fired. So I'm not sure if the problem is with my C# code or VS..

Comment: Hi, does it work on physical device ? Have a try this demo. https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/CoreLocation/

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT is there a way to simulate location changes on physical device ?

Comment: There is a way , however sample is in Xcode Project. You can create a gpx file in project, and put the coordinates obtained from Google Maps into this file and put them into the project root directory. I am not sure if this will work in Xamarin's project. Gpx file format is as follows. https://github.com/Dawnhan/SimulateLocation/blob/master/SimulateLocationDemo/SimulateLocationDemo/Location.gpx

Answer (score 0):

[stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44722395/locationmanager-didenterregion-not-called-in-xcode-9-simulator)

I don't know if this is the issue you are running into, but you need to make sure you have all three of the description keys in your info.plist for anything > iOS 11. That may be why it used to work, but doesn't work now.

The keys are as follows:

```
NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
```

There is a WWDC video talking about the changes in CoreLocation coming in iOS 13 so this may change yet again (I don't remember the details of that offhand).
[iOS 13 CoreLocation Video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/705/)